# I need to return the values ​of variables from a function for use in currency conversion

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I need to return the values ​​of variables from a function for use in currency conversion.
I get information about the rate of three currencies from the website of the Bank of Ukraine.

I already receive data from the function but cannot use it in others
I want to make a currency converter and in order not to make a request again I want to use them.

I don’t know where to write return. Moreover, the function has a function, the problem is, can you tell me how to process it.

There is a link to the site but it is in Ukrainian https://yurakhomitsky.github.io/exchange%20rates/

```js
var URItwo=`https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json`;
const XHR=new XMLHttpRequest();
 window.addEventListener("load",checkrate(),false);

function checkrate(e){

 XHR.addEventListener("readystatechange",function(){
  
 if((XHR.readyState===4) && (XHR.status===200)){
   var resultwo=JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);
            console.log(resultwo);
            for(var key in resultwo){
             if (resultwo[key].cc=="USD") {
               rateone.innerHTML=resultwo[key].txt +` `+resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2)+`грн`;
              cursUSD=resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2);
              console.log(cursUSD);
             }
             else if (resultwo[key].cc=="EUR") {
               ratetwo.innerHTML=resultwo[key].txt +` `+resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2)+`грн`;
              cursEUR=resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2);
               console.log(cursEUR);
             }
             else if (resultwo[key].cc=="PLN") {
               ratetree.innerHTML=resultwo[key].txt +` `+resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2)+`грн`;
              cursPLN=resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2);
              console.log(cursPLN);
              
             }
            }
    }
  
}, false);
    
XHR.open("GET",URItwo,true);
XHR.send();
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order not to make a request again you can prevese the response in some global variable such that it can be accessible from required methods.

```js
function fetchExchangeRateData(callback){
    const URItwo=`https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json`;
    const XHR=new XMLHttpRequest();
    XHR.open("GET",URItwo,true);
    XHR.onreadystatechange = function () { 
      if(XHR.readyState === 4 && XHR.status === 200){
            var resultwo=JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);
            console.log(resultwo);
            callback(resultwo, null);
       } else {
         callback(null, XHR.statusText); // return error
       }
    }
    XHR.send(); 
}

function manipulateDom(resultwo, error) {
  for(var key in resultwo){
   if (resultwo[key].cc=="USD") {
    rateone.innerHTML=resultwo[key].txt +` `+resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2)+`грн`;
    cursUSD=resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2);
    console.log(cursUSD);
   }
   else if (resultwo[key].cc=="EUR") {
    ratetwo.innerHTML=resultwo[key].txt +` `+resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2)+`грн`;
    cursEUR=resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2);
    console.log(cursEUR);
   }
   else if (resultwo[key].cc=="PLN") {
    ratetree.innerHTML=resultwo[key].txt +` `+resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2)+`грн`;
    cursPLN=resultwo[key].rate.toFixed(2);
    console.log(cursPLN);

   }
  }
}

function onLoad() {
  // you can use async and await keywords (Promises) of ES6 instead of callback.
  fetchExchangeRateData(function(data){
    // store data in some variable to use it in other function.
    manipulateDom(data);
    ...
    someOtherMethod(data);
  }); 
}

window.onload = onLoad;
```

Comment: Can you explain what a callback means and what it is for? And the data variable. Generally you can explain how everything works here?
And will I be able to use these (cursUSD,cursEUR,cursPLN)variables in other methods?

Comment: You can ready about callback from here - https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced

Comment: data variable holds response from the server